# WAMP server "DNS address could not be found"

Tags: dns, wamp

I have a WAMP server running on my PC for development, but I cannot access my sites. I can go to http://localhost/ and it shows [this](https://gyazo.com/db4acd51a15d4f0357e1eb4dc1f12e1e), but when I click on my project, it just gives [this error](https://gyazo.com/01063d9bf81815a7bebc53d7bf954b95). What am I doing wrong? I have a basic index.html page in the project directory, which should be enough to make the site run?

Thanks!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server configuration is off-topic.

Comment: @MarcB does that not count as a programming question?

Comment: dns configuration is not a programming issue.

Comment: Ok. Where can I go to ask about this?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618